# Load data into Snowflake using Pentaho

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pentaho

I am using pentaho 7.1 and trying to load data to Snowflake . The SQl is running fine on Snowflake. But in Pentaho I am getting error :

> Couldn't execute SQL: copy into "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC"."STG_DIMACTIVITY" Table 'DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.STG_DIMACTIVITY' does not exist

SQL used is :

```
copy into "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC"."STG_DIMACTIVITY"
from @my_s3_stage
FILES = ('MB_ACTIVITY.txt_0')
--pattern='.*MB_ACTIVITY.txt_0.*'
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' skip_header = 1) 
force=true;
```

Please let me know what i am missing here.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe pentaho is pointing at another DB or is running under another user that can't see the table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Thanks for reply. User and Db are same, i am using same user in snowflake. But when I am trying to fetch tables in schemas, pentaho is displaying only views and not the tables. Also version is 7.1. Can it be the reason?